# Comparing two tuples from different lists

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have this basic code in which I'm just trying to  compare each tuple in the first list (list1) with the corresponding tuple in the second list (list 2). If the tuple in list 2 is =  to the corresponding tuple in list1 minus the `'.vbproj'` then take both tuples and return them.

Then I need to print path + the tuple from list2 + the tuple from list1. I'm just stuck on how to do this.

```
path = "C:\Users\bg\Documents\Brent"

list1 = [ 'Brent.vbproj', 'Chris.vbproj', 'Nate.vbproj']
list2 = ['Brent', 'Chris', 'Nate']

def connect(list1, list2):

    for x, y in zip(string[0], string2[0]):
        if string(x) is string2(y):
            print x
            os.path.join(path, x, y)




x = connect(list1, list2)
y = connect(list1, list2)
```

I thought the `zip()` compared both tuples up to the minimal equivalence but I could be wrong?? I don't know, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is purpose of print after return?

Comment: Did you mean to call `connect` with `list1` and `list2` perhaps?

Comment: @oleg I just want to see if it's working properly or not

Comment: I think You should use os.path.join(path, x, y) instead of path + "\\" + x + "\\" + y

Comment: in this example the code after return in function will never run

Comment: I thouhgt you could still print things even after they were returned?

Comment: what Are You trying to compare?

Comment: I'm just trying to compare the first tuples from each list, then the second tuples from each and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `==` to test for equality. `is` tests for *identity*, the two sides being the *same object*. Also, your inputs `string` and `string2` are not functions, so you cannot call them. Just compare `x` and `y` directly:

```
if x == y:
```

Note that the function *ends* when you call `return`. The `print` statement on the next line is ignored, and the `for` loop ends as well.

Last but not least, you are only zipping the *first* elements of `string` and `string2`. I suspect you wanted to call this with `list1` and `list2`, at which point you probably wanted to pair up first `'Brent.vbproj'` and `'Brent'`, then `'Chris.vbproj'` and `'Chris'`, etc. If so, just pass the lists *without indexing*:

```
for x, y in zip(string, string2):
```

I doubt that you'll achieve what you want though; none of the value pairs from `list1` and `list2` will ever be equal.

Perhaps you wanted to look at the [`str.startswith()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)? Also, the [`os.path` library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) has functions you want to be familiar with if you are manipulating and testing filenames and paths. The [`os.path.join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join), [`os.path.splitext()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) and [`os.path.commonprefix()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.commonprefix) functions should be of particular interest to what I *think* you are trying to do here.

Note that your `path` variable also needs adjusting. Use a raw string, forward slashes or double the slashes:

```
path = r"C:\Users\bg\Documents\Brent"
path = "C:\\Users\\bg\\Documents\\Brent"
path = "C:/Users/bg/Documents/Brent"
```

as `\b` is the escape code for a backspace.

Comment: @martijin I changed the `is` to a `==` and it still doesnt work, now its saying ` List object can't be called` Thank you for the path advice too, I'll be sure to keep an eye on that in the future!

Comment: @Martijin So if I pass in the two lists without adding in an index it will just go tuple by tuple through it?

Comment: @bbesase: exactly; if you pair two *strings* instead, they'll go through them by pairs of characters: `zip('aa', 'bb')` becomes `[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'b')]`.

Comment: @martijin Awesome! It runs now, I just have to do some work with the output format! Thank you guys very much

Answer (score 1):

<del>you haven't defined `string` and `string2`</del> !! anyhow I understood your problem from your question text!!

comparing a tuple in  `list1` with ***corresponding*** tuple in `list2`, I myself as a beginner will do it in another way..

```
>>> path = r"C:\Users\bg\Documents\Brent"
>>> list1 = [ 'Brent.vbproj', 'Chris.vbproj', 'Nate.vbproj']
>>> list2 = ['Brent', 'Chris', 'Nate']
>>> for i in range(0, len(list1)):
    if i < len(list2):
        if list2[i][:] == list1[i][:len(list2[i])]:
            print(path + list2[i] + list1[i]) #Print syntax is for python 3


C:\Users\bg\Documents\BrentBrentBrent.vbproj
C:\Users\bg\Documents\BrentChrisChris.vbproj
C:\Users\bg\Documents\BrentNateNate.vbproj
>>>
```